# 1980s or earlier fantasy novel series, female warrior main character

Tags: story-identification, sword-and-sorcery

I'm looking for the title of a fantasy novel series I read a few books of when I was younger. At this point all I can really remember is that the female warrior protagonist MIGHT have been called Raven or something similar, and the covers tended to show her half naked in her warrior getup, wielding a sword.

Comment: Can you tell us more about the series?  For example, what year did you read them?  Can you recall any details about the plots of the novels?

Comment: I;m reminded of a novel from the same time period, *Frostflower and Thorn*. I doubt it's a match (the current answer seems likely to be correct). It did have at least one sequel (Frostflower and Windbourne* as I recall). The memorable part of this one for me was the coining of the very logical insult for a woman, "father-milker".

Comment: Might be a Mercedes Lackey Novel. Arrows of the queen etc. she wrote a lot of them back then, but covers were usually a bit more sedate. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercedes_Lackey

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Sounds *very much* like an old sword-and-sorcery paperback I have in my collection, but I haven't looked through it in ages. It's the first volume of a series of five about the same lead character. ***[Raven: Swordsmistress of Chaos](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?3944),*** first published in 1978, and written by Richard Kirk. (Or so it says on the cover -- we'll get back to that point of the real name of the author or authors in just a minute.) Here's a cover-scan of one edition of the book in question -- perhaps it will strike a chord in your memory.

[image: Cover of "Raven: Swordsmistress of Chaos". Tagline: "From out of the bonds of slavery there arose a beautiful warrior". The cover shows a scantily-clad, pale, blonde-haired woman holding a sword in both hands. A raven is sitting on her shoulder with its wings spread. In the background, lightning strikes in a red sky over mountains and several buildings.]

[Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0441705553) lists the full phrase "Raven: Swordsmistress of Chaos" as the title, but [ISFDB](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?3944) seems to think the "Raven" part, in such big letters on the cover, was just establishing the name of the entire *series*, and was *not* the first word of the official title of that first installment in the series. (I don't know who's right or wrong.)

Incidentally, just now, doing some online research, I learned that "Richard Kirk" was an early pen name used by the fantasy author who later become much better known after the award-winning novel *Mythago Wood* was published under his own name: [**Robert Holdstock**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Holdstock). According to Wikipedia's [Bibliography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Holdstock_bibliography#Raven_Series) of his published works, Holdstock actually *co-wrote* the first Raven book with Angus Wells, and he also wrote (apparently all on his own) #2 and #4 in that series, but had nothing to do with the writing of #3 and #5. The Wikipedia entry for the author [Angus Wells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angus_Wells) gives him full credit for those two sequels. (Since I've only read #1, and didn't even know until tonight that it was only published under a pseudonym, I can't swear of my own knowledge that Wikipedia has all these details *exactly right* regarding who wrote what.)

Amazon offers the following summary of what the first volume of the series is all about. Does any of this ring a bell for you?

> Raven -- She escaped the slavepens of Lyland--a beautiful girl with
> hair the color of summer sun, eyes as blue as the heavens, and a body
> that invited love. Rescued by sorcerer priests, she was schooled in
> every art of weaponry and combat. Her sword stained by the blood of
> legions, no man could defeat her. With her mysterious companion-mentor
> Spellbinder, and a great black bird to watch over them, Raven
> journeyed forth to her destiny--and the happy day of slaughtering Karl
> ir Donwayne, the cruel master who had tortured her mercilessly as a
> slave...